# Is there a way to find the last date before the date in the current row where the amount is not 0?

Tags: python, pandas

I've a pandas dataframe like:

```
Date, Amount
01/01/2020, 10
01/02/2020, 15
01/03/2020, 0
01/04/2020, 11
01/05/2020, 0
01/06/2020, 15
01/07/2020, 12
...
```

I would like to add a new column (namely "Before") the shows the number of days since the last 0 Amount. e.g.

```
Date, Amount, Before
01/01/2020, 10, 0
01/02/2020, 15, 0
01/03/2020, 0, 0
01/04/2020, 11, 1
01/05/2020, 0, 0
01/06/2020, 15, 1
01/07/2020, 12, 2
...
```

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create helper Series for compare `Amount` by `0` with consecutive sum by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html), filter out first group and create `first` Series for `0` rows per groups by [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html), then subtract days for number of days from previous `0`:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

g = df['Amount'].eq(0).cumsum()
first = df.groupby(g[g > 0])['Date'].transform('first')
df['Before'] = df['Date'].sub(first).dt.days.fillna(0).astype(int)

print (df)
        Date  Amount  Before
0 2020-01-01      10       0
1 2020-01-02      15       0
2 2020-01-03       0       0
3 2020-01-04      11       1
4 2020-01-05       0       0
5 2020-01-06      15       1
6 2020-01-07      12       2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

previous_zero_idx = (
    (df.Amount == 0)
    .astype(int)  # convert bool to int
    .replace(0, np.nan)
    .mul(df.index)  # row name if value is zero, else np.nan
    .ffill()  # forward fill
)

df['Before'] = (df.index - previous_zero).fillna(0).astype(int)
```